# parts of url disappear when using # inside href=""

Tags: php, url-rewriting, javascript, html

All the links of tags & taxonomies in the posts are perfectly fine and have correct links. But when i add a link on my theme's single.php & tried to use #id on href="" to jump on certain div, the url gets cut.

Example: Current location/url: http://127.0.0.1/wew/tvshows/the-simpsons/
then when i clicked the Comments i've added, the post just reloaded to: http://127.0.0.1/wew#comments instead of http://127.0.0.1/wew/tvshows/the-simpsons/#comments

What are the possible causes of this problem? Please name anything the might cause this problem 'cause it would take me decades if i check the files of my theme im customly editing one by one..

UPDATE: 
I just realised what the problem is, the  is causing the links to break so instead of removing it, i've decided to add the entire link to the #jumpid of my links.

example:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>#comments">Comments</a>
```

Comment: Please show the code used to create the links.

Comment: I have answered it below. But i also updated my questions with the codes i used to make it work. stackexchange is such a wonderful place, i learn more & more each day!

Comment: Please mark the question as answered, if so.

Answer (score 0):

Now i get the problem, the basehref's overiding the link so i decided to just add the permalink in the scroll link i've made. I've fixed it by using `<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>#comments` on the link in the single.php of my theme.